# Adding Types to Created ModuleDefinition

Tags: collections, types, .net-assembly, mono.cecil

It's not as straightforward as it seems; using  `myModule.Types.Add(fully defined type from another module)` throws `ArgumentException: "Type already attached!"` How could that be when the module is created from scratch? I got the same exception after Clear()ing the Collection, removing even the default empty Type.

I also tried using Types.CopyTo and various Array operations, but the Collection and Array size is fixed internally. The only way to expand it is by Adding, but Attach rejects Types.

Comment: Could you include a short code example that reproduces the error?

Comment: It doesn't look like an error since it appears to be by design that a member of one module can't be attached to another. So that just leaves the problem of how types, properties, methods and fields can be dynamically reproduced in a new module.